# changing color of glyphicon svg from black to add a blue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, glyphicons

I know how to alter the color of a Bootstrap glyphicon.  However I have inherited a CSS in-house framework in which I tried to use the same principles in which I create a class with color of blue but it does not work

We just have the option of altering this CSS framework too much, especially not replacing it with bootstrap.  I'm wondering if it is possible to add

```
icon-weather-blue  (does not exist , only white and black)
```

Here are the 2 existing Classes for this

```
.icon-weather-white{background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20standalone%3D%22no%22%3F%3E%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2264%22%20height%3D%2264%22%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3Ecircle%2C%20ellipse%2C%20line%2C%20path%2C%20polygon%2C%20polyline%2C%20rect%2C%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%20white%20!important%3B%20stroke%3A%20white%20!important%3B%20%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cg%20stroke%3D%22%23363c3d%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M18.12%2053.084h28.836c2.15-.03%206.54-.804%208.957-4.326%201.433-2.068%202.047-5.79%201.116-9.112-.945-3.368-3.932-6.3-6.527-7.5.356-3.044-1.375-6.266-3.778-8.048-2.594-1.925-5.972-2.31-8.35-.993-3.45-4.036-8.09-5.866-12.485-5.367-6.71.763-11.318%205.7-11.773%2014.52C6.73%2036.4%206.47%2044.162%209.42%2048.782c1.927%203.022%205.38%204.272%208.7%204.304z%22%20stroke-width%3D%225.5%22%20stroke-linecap%3D%22round%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M13.95%2032.663c-6.24-1.672-9.943-8.085-8.27-14.325%201.67-6.24%208.084-9.942%2014.324-8.27%203.658.98%206.616%203.67%207.936%207.22l-10.963%204.077z%22%20stroke-width%3D%223%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');background-repeat:no-repeat}

.icon-weather{background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20standalone%3D%22no%22%3F%3E%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2264%22%20height%3D%2264%22%3E%3Cg%20stroke%3D%22%23363c3d%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M18.12%2053.084h28.836c2.15-.03%206.54-.804%208.957-4.326%201.433-2.068%202.047-5.79%201.116-9.112-.945-3.368-3.932-6.3-6.527-7.5.356-3.044-1.375-6.266-3.778-8.048-2.594-1.925-5.972-2.31-8.35-.993-3.45-4.036-8.09-5.866-12.485-5.367-6.71.763-11.318%205.7-11.773%2014.52C6.73%2036.4%206.47%2044.162%209.42%2048.782c1.927%203.022%205.38%204.272%208.7%204.304z%22%20stroke-width%3D%225.5%22%20stroke-linecap%3D%22round%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M13.95%2032.663c-6.24-1.672-9.943-8.085-8.27-14.325%201.67-6.24%208.084-9.942%2014.324-8.27%203.658.98%206.616%203.67%207.936%207.22l-10.963%204.077z%22%20stroke-width%3D%223%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');background-repeat:no-repeat}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the stroke color in the URI (using the .icon-weather example) here: `stroke%3D%22%23363c3d%22`. `%3D` is =, `%22` is ", and `%23` is #, so this string can be read as `stroke="#363c3d"`. So changing just this portion: `363c3d` would change the stroke color. See [example](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/21fb90197ea6aa57ccd304c11e0852fc?editors=010).